# Regex for isfile function in Julia

Tags: io, julia, string-matching

The `isfile()` function seems to only work for exact matches of filenames. Is there a way to make it work with regex strings? It throws a `MethodError: no method matching joinpath(::Regex)` error when the string in the argument is replaced by a regex string.

Comment: `isfile` returns a Boolean. With a Regex, multiple files could match the Regex, and it isn't clear which one should be `isfile`d and should the function return a vector of Bools or true if any file matching Regex is found. More details in the question would help.

Comment: I see, I thought `isfile` checks whether a file exists, and if it does it returns true and false if it does not. I would've expected that if any file matches the regex expression then it should return true, and false if not.

Basically, I'm trying to determine whether any file which matches the regex exists in the directory. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: This could work: `any(fn for fn in readdir(".") if !isnothing(match(r".*\.txt",fn)))` if you replace `"."` and `r".*\.txt"` by your values. But to get the actual filename, you would want to use something else (like a `for` loop)

Comment: @DanGetz That `any` doesn't look right; it is given a set of strings. Rather than the conditional filter, just `any(!isnothing(match(r".*\.txt",fn)) for fn in readdir("."))`

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Yep. You are correct. In any case, a good question (and maybe a missing standard function) would be a method to get the first matching filename. And maybe adding the `isfile` condition would filter out non-regular files: `any(isfile(fn) && !isnothing(match(r".*\.txt", fn)) for fn in readdir("."))`

Comment: Maybe you can use https://github.com/vtjnash/Glob.jl ? It isn't regex, but uses the common file search wildcards, like `*` and `?`. For a function like you describe, I would suggest the name `anyfile(...)`. I highly doubt it would be part of Base, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite regex, but see e.g. the [Glob.jl package](https://github.com/vtjnash/Glob.jl) which lets you do POSIX-style wildcards.  For example, if you want to check if there are any `*.jpg` files in the current directory, you could do `!isempty(readdir(glob"*.jpg"))`